# What is the difference between /proc/kmsg and dmsg?

Tags: linux, debugging, logging, linux-kernel, kernel

We normally do `cat /proc/kmsg` or `dmesg` to see the kernel logs from user space.

I understand the `dmesg` is a circular buffer which copies from `kmsg`. But is `kmsg` also not a circular buffer?

What is the difference and relation between them?

Comment: Have a look at [How to read ring buffer within linux kernel space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533708/how-to-read-ring-buffer-within-linux-kernel-space) for a great answer with nice references.

Answer (score 6):

Loosely speaking dmesg is a program that dumps /proc/kmsg.  In addition, it provides some filtering capabilities to weed out logs that the user isn't interested in.

Comment: ye I know dmesg copies from /proc/kmsg. 
But as dmesg; is kmsg also a circular buffer ?

Comment: @SaurabhSengar yes

Comment: circular buffer is implemented by kernel itself, dmesg is just a util to read this circular via kernel interface /proc/kmsg

Answer (score 3):

The output of */proc/kmsg* can be directed to a file when collecting large amount of logs so that no logs are lost.

*dmesg* is circular buffer and previous logs get overwritten once the buffer is full.

Comment: Is kmsg not a circular buffer ?